# Loading SVG images in Gatsby from Sanity

Tags: typescript, svg, graphql, gatsby, sanity

What is the right approach to load SVG images from a Sanity CMS in a Gatsby (v3) website? The [Sanity documentation](https://www.sanity.io/docs/presenting-images) states that

> GIF and SVG pass through the image pipeline untouched, but if you want them scaled they will need to be output as one of the three formats above.

But with Gatsby not accepting SVG in the `gatsby-image` I haven't found a clean way to import them, the provided examples are always showing bitmap formats.

My current solution is the following, but I find it not very efficient:

```js
import React, {FC, ReactElement} from 'react'
import clientConfig from "../../client-config";
import {getGatsbyImageData} from 'gatsby-source-sanity'
import { ImageNode } from 'gatsby-source-sanity/lib-es5/images/getGatsbyImageProps';

type industryProps = {
  industryTitle: string;
  industryDescription: string;
  link: string;
  icons: any;
};

const Industry: FC<industryProps> = (props): ReactElement => {
  const getImageData = (asset?: ImageNode) => getGatsbyImageData(asset, { width: 320 }, clientConfig.sanity);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{props.industryTitle}</h1>
      <p>{props.industryDescription}</p>
      {
        props.icons && props.icons.map(
          (icon: any) => {            
            const image = getImageData(icon.industryIconSVG.asset);
            const url = (image?.images?.sources[0]?.srcSet.split("?")[0]);
            return (
            <>
              <p>{icon.industryIconName}</p>
              <p>{url && <img src={url} />}</p>
            </>
          )}
        )
      }
      
    </>
  )
}

export default Industry;
```

Is there a simpler way to get the URL of the image? Now I need to use `getGatsbyImageData`to get an object that contain a srcSet that I still need to split because the provided query parameter are not working!

Comment: Are you fetching the full SVG from Sanity isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I did follow the "Kitchen Sink" example from Sanity where you fetch the whole data `_rawContent` in a parent component, then map each `content` node to various components.
It works fine for normal images.